# Access Azure variables in angular5

Tags: angular, azure, angular5

I have angular5 project (pure angular5 client side project), I want to access azure environment variables at client side. Can anyone help me to find out a way , by which I can access environment variables in angular?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you hosting the Angular Website as a App Service on Azure? If yes you might want to add a Web.config in it and use it to get certain variables

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly access from Angular itself, you need to build a backend service which holds the configuration.

if its via DotNet use appsettings to configure the settings and you can access it via configuraiton.

Design an API to return the settings back to the client app and then you can use them